# Как в GAS получить критерии фильтра колонки?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

В зависимости от того какого контрагента выберет пользователь в фильтре, должен отправляться email этому контрагенту из GAS. Как в GAS получить критерий  фильтрации?
Я не смог нагуглить как это сделать. Исходя из информации в англоязычных источника это сделать невозможно.
Может кто-то подсказать?
Как вариант на листе можно расположить формулу, которая брала бы значения отфильтрованных строк и если все они равны, то возвращала бы значение, которое эквивалентно критерию фильтрации. А результат этой формулы используется GAS. Подскажите какую формулу можно использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю, используется обычный фильтр по значению (который автоматически выпадает при нажатии на кнопку фильтра). Допустим, в 1 столбце есть такие данные:

```
name (название столбца)
a
a
b
b
c
c
c
```

Стоит фильтр, допустим по значению **b** (то есть убраны все галочки, кроме, допустим **b**)

След. код вернет это **b** (код написан для нового рантайма v8 - для старого - перепишите на старом синтаксисе)

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // текущий файл таблиц
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // текущий лист 
  const filter = sheet.getFilter(); // получаем фильтр на этом листе
  
  const fc = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(1); // FilterCriteria по 1 столбцу
  
  const hv = fc.getHiddenValues(); // Получаем все скрытые значения
  
  const allValuesObj = {}; // далее получаем ВСЕ значения
  
  sheet
  .getRange('A2:A')
  .getValues()
  .forEach(function(row){
    if(row[0]) allValuesObj[row[0]] = row[0];
  });
  
  const allValues = Object.keys(allValuesObj);

  // Находим разницу массивов - то есть, то , по чем идет фильтр
  const difference = allValues.filter(x => !hv.includes(x)); 
  
  Logger.log(difference[0]); // В лог записываем это значение (b в этом примере)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает без корректировок. difference  возвращает все значения критерия выбранные в фильтре.